# Vagrant: how to reload VM memory settings

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I need to increase my memory settings which are now:

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|

     vb.memory = "1024"
  end
```

The problem is that even increasing the vb.memory, when I issue a "free -m" from the virtual machine, I don't see any change in available memory.
Tried with:

```
vagrant reload
```

without luck. Is there a non-destructive way to change the memory settings of the VM ?
Thanks

Comment: That's odd. Changing the amount of memory in the Vagrantfile and running `vagrant reload` has always worked for me. Can you edit your question to include the host OS, base box, and versions of VirtualBox and Vagrant? Ideally you could strip down your Vagrantfile to the minimum that still results in this issue, post the whole file, and then we can see if anyone is able to reproduce what you're experiencing.

Comment: can you also paste the result of `free -m` and `cat /proc/meminfo`